# How to wrap all containing text based on the contents inside a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

Complete novice in JS/jQuery here just trying to do what I can while we fill in a senior dev role at work.

I'm trying to add to the end of these  tags "Discount applied in cart". I was going to do this using an :after and "content" tag in css however this tag should only be added to the first 3  tags listed below and not the last 4.

```
<a class="externalLink">SAVE X%</a>
<a class="externalLink">SPEND $X SAVE X%</a>
<a class="externalLink">EXTRA X% OFF - ONLINE ONLY</a>
```

---

```
<a class="externalLink">BONUS GIFT</a>
<a class="externalLink">BUY 2 FOR $X</a>
<a class="externalLink">COMPLIMENTARY DELIVERY</a>
<a class="externalLink">REDEEM $X</a>
```

I tried googling a solution and stitched different bits of code together. I have tried the following to at least make the first one work, but unfortunately it didn't work

```
$("a.externalLink:contains('SAVE')").html(function(_, html) {
return html.wrapAll('<span class="applied-cart" />');
});
```

Essentially what I'm hoping to do is change the code to the following

```
<a class="externalLink"><span class="applied-cart">SAVE X%</span></a>
```

with the css

```
.applied-cart:after {
content="Applied in cart";
}
```

Comment: Well first problem is that none of the links contains `SAVE`, they contain `Save,save`

Comment: If it's *always* the first 3 tags in the container you could use `.slice(0, 3)` or `:lt(4)`

Comment: @carsten Sorry, they are all capitalised. I just edited the code.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan unfortunately not. Only one will ever appear on the page at a time.

Comment: `return html` - html here is a string, so .wrapAll won't work.  You might be able to use `$("a.externalLink:contains('SAVE')").wrapAll("<span...`

Comment: I'd go with addClass and change the css, doesn't seem to be any reason to add the span  https://jsfiddle.net/4qoge7b5/

Comment: Thanks @freedomn-m this worked perfectly :D. I obviously just over complicated this.

Answer (score 0):

Using your existing `$("a.externalLink:contains('SAVE')")`, you can use `.addClass` to apply your class directly to the `a` without the need to `.wrap` or otherwise add additional HTML.

```js
$("a.externalLink:contains('SAVE')").addClass("applied")
```

```css
.applied:after {
  color:rebeccapurple;
  content:"Applied in cart";
  margin-left:1em;
}

a { display:block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="externalLink">SAVE X%</a>
<a class="externalLink">SPEND $X SAVE X%</a>
<a class="externalLink">EXTRA X% OFF - ONLINE ONLY</a>
<a class="externalLink">BONUS GIFT</a>
<a class="externalLink">BUY 2 FOR $X</a>
<a class="externalLink">COMPLIMENTARY DELIVERY</a>
<a class="externalLink">REDEEM $X</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

No JS required, just use the power of advanced CSS selectors:

```css
div {
  white-space: pre-line; /* just for better readability of the output */
}

.externalLink:not(.externalLink:nth-of-type(3)~.externalLink)::after {
  content: " Content added by CSS";
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="externalLink">SAVE X%</a>
  <a class="externalLink">SPEND $X SAVE X%</a>
  <a class="externalLink">EXTRA X% OFF - ONLINE ONLY</a>

  <a class="externalLink">BONUS GIFT</a>
  <a class="externalLink">BUY 2 FOR $X</a>
  <a class="externalLink">COMPLIMENTARY DELIVERY</a>
  <a class="externalLink">REDEEM $X</a>
</div>
```